# How to pass a variable ( a numerical ID) from a page to another through click

Tags: javascript

I have auto generated content, and auto generated buttons. The buttons have the same link, only the variable differs. How can i pass the variable on the button click to another page ( from the button onclick link).

After I generate the button, i give it a function, something like:

```
$('.Button').click(function() { window.location ='page.html'; });
```

Comment: Post your example. Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply use a query string.

```
http://mysite.com/page2.html?myid=1234
```

Based on your comment you could do:

```
$('.Button').click(function() { 
     var myid = 1234;
     window.location ='page.html?myid=' + myid; 
});
```

Comment: After I generate the button, i give it a function, something like: $('.Button').click(function() {
                        window.location ='page.html';
                        });

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it using pure html/js - try to add hash to page like in code above:

```
onClick {
 document.location = "/yourPage.html#id";
}

onLoad {
var id = window.location.hash;
}
```

Also, you can save id in SessionStorage, LocalStorage or Cookies.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about the variable being public you can add it to the url as a query string `http://domain/pagename.html?varname=2&othervar=2`.

If its on the same domain you can add it to sessionStorage

```
sessionStorage["varname"] = x;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set it as a variable in the URL query string, and then read the query string for the value.

Something like:

```
index.html?variable=value
```

Another option would be to set a cookie with the variable key/value, and then read the cookie when the page loads.

```
document.cookie=variable + "=" + value;
```